# how to make a MS SQL create view with unique ids?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, multiple-tables, create-view

#### Background:

i was first asked to do a website using mysql as the database, after that was done and sent, the clients asked me to convert it to mssql, and 3 tiers.

i did the classes and functions for transferring data between the servers, so the 3 tiers bit is about halfway done. the thing i'm struggling with now is the MsSQL.

#### Question:

the MySQL version of the question looks like this:

```
select a.id as a_id, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.agent_code,
       b.id as b_id, b.user_id, b.status_admin 
from tbl_user a 
  inner join tbl_testimonia b 
    on a.id = b.user_id 
where b.status_admin=0  
group by a.id
order by b.id desc
```

what it does is return testimonials that aren't approved yet, grouped to each user;

---

#### Where I am stuck:

i cant convert this to MSSQL

My best try:

- Create view;

as in:

```
    create view test as
    (
    select a.id as a_id, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.agent_code,
    b.id as b_id, b.user_id,  b.status_admin 
    from tbl_user a inner join tbl_testimonia b on a.id = b.user_id 
    where b.status_admin=0 and a.id in  
    (
    select a.id from tbl_user a 
    inner join tbl_testimonia b 
    on a.id = b.user_id
    where b.status_admin=0 
    group by a.id
    )
    )
```

this selects what i want, but the *id* field of the create view **cant be grouped**, meaning the id field is not unique and can have the same value.

I guess my question up to this point is, how do i uniquely select the id field in the view?
sure i can do it in PHP, but i could have done that a month ago when i first encountered the problem.

I've been trying to find the answer for a while now but cant seem to find the answer unique to my question

- edit: the MSSQL doesn't work because even though the subquery is selecting unique ids the **in** statement in the main query makes this irrelevent
- edit: example output::~ (in MySql the 3rd field is ommited)

  ```
  | a_id  |  firstN | LastN |  agent_code  |   b_id  |  user_id |status_admin|
  +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | 32    |  fn1    | ln1   |  AC123213    |   14    |   32     |   0        |
  | 41    |  fn2    | ln2   |  12345678    |   15    |   41     |   0        |
  | 32    |  fn1    | ln1   |  AC123213    |   16    |   32     |   0        |
  ```
- edit: **QUESTION SOLVED** a big thx to Lieven for the simple answer

Comment: am i asking the wrong question? am i paraphrasing wrong? how do i pull all the experts to the field?

Comment: Before looking to hard at your view, why can't you convert the MySQL version to MSSQL? It should run like it is?! If it doesn't return the right results in MSSQL, so it shouldn't have in MySQL.

Comment: of course i tried the copy paste method first, but i hit a snag at **group by** with error saying that i cant select anything else that isn't in the group by clause, hence the subquery, which didnt work

Comment: You are right, I missed that. How about applying an aggregate function to each field you don't explicitly want to group by? (what does MySQL actually returns if you have two records with id = 1? One record or two? If one, what are the values of the other fields? The first ones, last ones, ... ?)

Comment: umm, a bit more explanation? do u mean like adding sum to each field or something? how do you put an aggregate function to a 'varchar' field? i'll try this first and come back.

Comment: MIN or MAX would make more sense with a VARCHAR field

Comment: From a quote from Quassnoi regarding MySQL *An unaggregated expression in GROUP BY returns an arbitrary record from each group and is not supposed to be used if the values vary. You can return any record from master_table (they will all be the same within each group) but not from lang_table. There is no guarantee on which record will be returned, nada, niente.* so in that light, the aggregate function solution should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already explained yourself, unlike SQL Server, MySQL allows grouping by with unaggregated expressions like this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        column
```

As an unaggregated expression in GROUP BY returns an arbitrary record from each group and is not supposed to be used if the values vary you should be able to use the following statement as an equivalent in SQL Server

```
select a.id as a_id
       , MIN(a.first_name)
       , MIN(a.last_name)
       , MIN(a.agent_code)
       , MIN(b.id as b_id)
       , MIN(b.user_id)
       , MIN(b.status_admin)
from   tbl_user a 
       inner join tbl_testimonia b on a.id = b.user_id 
where  b.status_admin=0  
group by 
       a.id
order by 
       b.id desc
```

Comment: cool, it works! i assumed u could only put an aggregated function on  *number* fields. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have non repetitive ids you can

```
select DISTINCT a.id from tbl_user a 
inner join tbl_testimonia b 
  on a.id = b.user_id where b.status_admin=0
```

in your sub query

Comment: the subquery is already selecting distinct values, but the first query still selects the same thing. should i remove the subquery to make the question simpler?